# get object value from an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, use-effect

Im quite new to front-end development. I am using React.

My problem:
How to extract object value that are within array?

```js
   myArr = [[{a: 1, b: 2}], [{a: 1, b:2}], [{a: 1, b:2}]]
   // I want to extract only the values of b and make them into array 
   // my asnwer should look like this: 
   // [2,2,2]
```

My Approach:

```js
  const [answerArr, setAnswerArr] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const extractCode = () => {
      const res = myArr.map((item)=>{
          ????
       })
    };
    extractCode();
  }, [codeArr]);
```

I've tried using map method...but I am struggling very much...
If you could help me i would learn so much!

Comment: ???? should be `return item[0].b`.

Comment: `myArr.flat().map(({b}) => b)`

Comment: myArr.map(([{ b }]) => b)

Answer (score 3):

Your code should look something like this

```
 const res = myArr.map(item => item[0].b)
```